# QEMU-KVM Linux virtualization on the command line

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu, arch-linux

I recently discovered that `qemu-kvm` has a very promising `-curses` option that, instead of starting an X window, will show a nice ncurses output from the guest suitable for managing a Linux guest from the command line (or, more satisfyingly, within a screen session, or even over ssh).

So I tried this out, and discovered that my Arch Linux guest goes into a "Graphics Mode" rendering this feature useless. From what I have been able to ascertain, the issue is that the guest kernel initializes a framebuffer to allow for higher than 80x60 character resolution (and pretty graphics). So I went on a hunt to find a way to prevent the guest kernel from starting the framebuffer. I have tried a variety of kernel parameters, `nomodeset`, `fb=false`, `vga=0x0FF`, `vga=ask` (and subsequently selecting a `VGA` rather than a `VESA` mode), to no avail: every time `qemu-kvm -curses` reports being in a "Graphic Mode" on the guest (after the initial boot menus), and I am unable to interact with the guest from a command line terminal on the host.

Is there any easy way to keep the guest kernel in the same mode that it starts in (no framebuffer) without changing a kernel build parameter? If not, what kernel build options should I change to compile a kernel without framebuffer support? Is there a better way to get a VM login from a terminal on the host in pure text mode (suitable to run in a screen session on the host, for example) without resorting to running sshd on the guest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the underlying module that needs to be disabled is `fbcon`, however Arch's kernel does not compile it as a module, so blacklisting it out. It might still be possible to identify and disable the particular driver that `fbcon` launches but no such driver is listed by `lsmod`, so `qemu-kvm`'s driver is compiled into Arch. To disable `fbcon` itself, you have to use its own strange boot option syntax:

```
fbcon=map:99
```

where `99` is just some arbitrarily large number that is greater than the number of framebuffer devices on the system (usually 1-2).

See [fbcon.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

`vga16fb.modeset=0` worked for me in the past (in Ubuntu).  Also in Ubuntu, blacklisting all framebuffer modules (vga16fb included) worked too.

Comment: `vga16fb.modeset=0` didn't seem to do anything in Arch. I'll try blacklisting framebuffer modules, as you suggest. Is there a good reference to look up modules (particularly framebuffer modules) so I do not miss any?

Comment: Ubuntu has /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf

Comment: Thanks! Found it (or something approximating it) [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/net/scratch/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf). May try it out in addition to disabling `fbcon` to see where it'll get me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it like this:

```
TERM=dumb qemu-kvm -curses ...
```

Comment: No luck. The issue appears to be the guest kernel changing modes, rather than the host terminal.

Comment: @malloc47: Ah; then the issue is with Arch Linux, with which I cannot help you.